# compass watch is broken - Errno::EACCES on line ["1143"]

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass-sass

I recently installed OSX Mavericks on my Mac and before that I didn't have any problems using compass watch.

Now, when I try to do a "compass watch" in the Terminal

```
Errno::EACCES on line ["1143"] of /Users/Dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /Users/Dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.10/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/.listen_test
```

As you may have noticed, I have installed Ruby through rvm (I tried that to fix the problem, no luck).

My paths file (/etc/paths) looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

My .bash_profile file looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

And my .bashrc file looks like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

When I do "echo $PATH" in the Terminal, I get the following:

```
/Users/Dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/Dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/Dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/Dan/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

My gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /Users/Dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Bonus info: I have another project running which uses grunt, and when I do "grunt server" and edit my .scss files they are being perfectly watched and compiled into css.

Br
Dan

Comment: Make sure that all the dirs and the target along the path:
/Users/Dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.10/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/.listen_test have proper rights i.e. '+xr' in terms of chmod, and proper owner i.e. those, from which the app has run.